# Fluently Configure Access Database with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The following configuration is throwing an exception with an inner message that says "Could not compile the mapping document".

```
return Fluently.Configure()
.Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.JetDriverConfiguration.Standard
        .ConnectionString(x => x.DatabaseFile(@"C:\Users\username\Documents\App_Survey.accdb")))
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Question>())
  //.ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Question is a domain object that is compiled into the same assembly as the mappings. Can someone tell me how I might being to resolve this?

Comment: if the error message says that your mappings may be flawed, it'd be a good idea to post your mapping as well.

Comment: Please post the full exception.  Use Exception.ToString() and post that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the exception is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate.JetDriver' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

You need to download the "NHibernate.JetDriver" separately from [nhcontrib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/) project.
Checkout the source code from Source Forge: https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/trunk and then build it (/trunk/src/NHibernate.JetDriver).